# Cover ajax calls in jasmine test

Tags: javascript, ajax, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write jasmine unit test for javascript file which has Ajax call. Not aware how to cover the part under 'Success' function through jasmine test.

Code snippet is as below

```
function getGroups(){
 var defer = _$q.defer();
  $.ajax( {
      url: 'xyz',
      data: 'abc',
      async: false,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'xml',
      success: function( xml ) {
          var groups = [];
          groups = xml.getElementsByTagName( 'requiredGroup' );
          defer.resolve( groups );
      }
  } );
  return defer.promise;
}
```

I tried below solutions but this does not cover the code under the success function:

```
 describe("getGroups() does ajax call", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      spyOn($, 'ajax');
    });

   it("call on success", function() {
   getGroups();
   expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you want to test? the ajax call or the success callback. Be sure that someone tested that it behaves as expected.

If you want to test the success callback you might want to extract it to some variable and then just test it:

```
function getGroups(){
 var defer = _$q.defer();
  $.ajax( {
      url: 'xyz',
      data: 'abc',
      async: false,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'xml',
      success: function(xml) {
          onSuccess(xml, defer);
      }
  } );

  return defer.promise;
}

const onSuccess = function( xml, defer) {
       var groups = [];
       groups = xml.getElementsByTagName( 'requiredGroup' );
       defer.resolve( groups );
}
```

Comment: @vli020 I want to test success callback. how can it works without extracting to some variable.

Comment: You can't, as it is an anonymous function. And in your unit test you probably don't want to do a real call to your back end